# Virtual machine access

Tags: linux, virtualbox, oracle, jboss

My host OS is Windows 7 and guest - Oracle Linux. I've got an appliaction which is running using `JBoss` and `ngnix` on guest. How can I connect to this app throgh host OS?

Answer (score 1):

Configure your network adapter in bridged mode instead of nat.

Answer (score -1):

Check ip address of your guest OS, then simply access your app from the host OS via guest IP.